# Dynamic Image Location from Web Config

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to .NET and I want to add an image to an ASPX page (WebForms) but I want the image location to be configurable in the web config file. Everything I have found is much more complex than I would expect it to be. Below, the top line on the ASPX page is what I'm trying to get to work while the second line works fine with the image location hard coded. What am I missing?

ASPX page:

```
<asp:Image ID="MainLogo" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%=MainLogo%>' />
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/main-logo.png" />
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class SiteMaster : MasterPage
    {
        public string MainLogo = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MainLogoLocation"];

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Page.Title = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteTitle"];

        }
    }
```

Web Config:

```
<add key="MainLogoLocation" value="~\Images\main-logo.png"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In web Config 
you can set path

```
<add key="MainLogoLocation" value="~\Images\main-logo.png"/>
```

In aspx page

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"/>
```

cs code
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
{
    Image1.ImageUrl= WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MainLogoLocation"].ToString();

}
```

Comment: This works, but you don't need code to access the app settings, you can use an expression, e.g. 

    <appSettings>
      <add key="ImageLocation" value="\Images\" />
    </appSettings>
    <img src="~<%$ AppSettings:ImageFolder %>/main-logo.png" />

Answer (score 0):

Complex Solution:

You can easily do this by creating your own Expression Builder. In ASP.Net an expression would look like <%$ SomePrefix:SomeProperty %>.

Expression builders are registered in the web.config with a prefix.  So the above would call an expression builder with a prefix of "SomePrefix" and request "SomeProperty"

Creating a custom expression builder isn't to difficult.  You basically just create a class that inherits from "ExpressionBuilder", then you implement the GetCodeExpression and GetEvalData method.

Then you have to register it in the web.config, e.g.

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true">
    <expressionBuilders>
      <add expressionPrefix="path" 
        type="XYZ.PathExpressionBuilder, YourAssemblyName"/>
    </expressionBuilders>
  </compilation>
</system.web>
```

http://haacked.com/archive/2006/11/29/Express_Yourself_With_Custom_Expression_Builders.aspx/